# UITableView cell size of screen

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have a table view controller with a navigation controller, and when there is no data for the table view, I want to display a single table cell with instructions on how to add new data. I can display the table cell, but I do not understand how I can get the height of the cell to span the visible height (table height - navigation item height). My goal is to have the label inside of my table cell be vertically centered in the device. I've tried using `self.tableView.frame.height`, but that gives me the scrollable height, which is larger than the visible area.

Edit: I failed to mention I'm doing this from `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a Good Enough™ answer to my own question:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
    return tableView.frame.height - (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!
}
```

Comment: you forgot about status bar height: `self.tableView.frame.height - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height - UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height`